# Где хранить файлы cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Извините, вопрос возможно (скорее всего) глупый, но в начальной документации не нашел. Где хранить и как ссылаться на свои файлы в cakephp 3.0.~ ?
Спасибо.

Comment: а какие то свои классы помимо контроллеров,моделей, эвентов? создайте директорию в `src`, и используйте соответствующий неймспейс, на него и ссылаейтесь

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ru/intro/cakephp-folder-structure.html

Comment: @Slava перевод доков кстати весьма печальный.

Comment: @teran нормальный, главное суть

Answer (score 0):

Папка webroot в ней создать свою папку например files и там хранить.
Файлы будут доступны по адресу mysite.ru/files/имя_файла